# printf of int value returns only first character

Tags: c, codelite

When I run the code below i get this output:

> Podaj ilosc liczb: 12
>
> Podaj liczbe nr. 0 : 53
>
> Podaj liczbe nr. 1 : 24
>
> Podaj liczbe nr. 2 : 53
>
> Podaj liczbe nr. 3 : 24
>
> Podaj liczbe nr. 4 : 66
>
> Podaj liczbe nr. 5 : 99
>
> Podaj liczbe nr. 6 : 3
>
> Podaj liczbe nr. 7 : 0
>
> Podaj liczbe nr. 8 : 5
>
> Podaj liczbe nr. 9 : 2
>
> Podaj liczbe nr. 10 : 5
>
> Podaj liczbe nr. 11 : 2
> Twoje liczby w odwrotnej kolejnosci:
> 2  5  2  5  0  3  9  6  2  5  2  5

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

char tablo[100];
int k,i;
printf("Podaj ilosc liczb: ");
scanf("%d", &k);fflush(stdin);
for(i=0; i<k; i++){
                 printf("\nPodaj liczbe nr. %d : ", i);
                 scanf("%c", &tablo[i]);fflush(stdin);
                 }
printf("Twoje liczby w odwrotnej kolejnosci: \n");
for(i=k-1;i>=0;i--){
                    printf("%3c",tablo[i]);
                    }
                    printf("\n \n");

return 0;
}
```

Why? How to fix it? I just want my numbers in the reverse sequence.

Comment: scanf(" %c",&table[i]); Try adding a space before %c

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: use `puts` to just print a string without any formatting, calling `printf` without any arguments other than the formatting string for that purpose is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Mgetz  Disagree with "calling printf without any arguments other than the formatting string for that purpose is undefined behavior".  Calling `printf()` with incorrect or insufficient agreements is UB.  Simple calling `printf("Hello")` is not UB.  Further `printf("Podaj ilosc liczb: ")` is not the same as `puts("Podaj ilosc liczb: ")` as the latter adds `\n`. Better to suggest `fputs()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [using scanf in pointers to integer array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378346/using-scanf-in-pointers-to-integer-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only scanning for single characters, not actual numbers. Instead, `tablo` should be an array of `int` (not `char`), and instead of using `%c` for `scanf` and `printf`, you should use `%d`.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading and writing individual characters, not integers. Try running your program with, say, `x` or `*` as input; it will just print the characters you gave it without trying to interpret them as decimal integers.

To read integers (interpreting the sequence `"123"` as the decimal number `123`), use `scanf("%d", ...)` to read into an `int` object, and `printf("%d", ...)` to print the values -- and define `tablo` as an array of `int` rather than of `char`. (And don't forget to check the value returned by `scanf`, so you can tell whether it succeeded or failed.)

And don't use `fflush(stdin)`. The behavior of `fflush` on input streams is undefined, and you don't really need it anyway. Later you might want a way to discard invalid input, but `fflush` isn't the answer.

Comment: Alternately, he could simply change the conversion specifier to `%hhd` if his values will all fit into the `char` data type.

Comment: @JohnBode only if `char` is signed by default. Otherwise, it'd have to be `%hhu`

Answer (score 1):

The `%c` conversion specifier tells `scanf` to read a single *character* from the input stream; when you type "53", only the character `'5'` will be read.  If you want to read *numerical* values and store them in a `char` data type, you need to use the `%hhd` conversion specifier:

```
scanf( "%hhd", &tablo[i] );
```

Note that if you want to store any value greater than 128, you'll need to use a wider data type such as `int` and the appropriate conversion specifier (`%d` for `int`, `%hd` for `short`, `%ld` for `long`, etc).

Don't use `fflush` on input streams like `stdin`; the behavior isn't defined, and it may not do what you intend.